# Segment lines with incremental attributes - PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, line, segment

I have been trying to segment lines at specific interval (2000 m) using `St_LineSubstring` function. So far, I managed to accomplish that with the following code:

```
SELECT ST_LineSubstring(the_geom, 2000.00*n/length,
  CASE
    WHEN 2000.00*(n+1) < length THEN 2000.00*(n+1)/length
    ELSE 1
  END) As the_geom
FROM
  (SELECT ST_LineMerge(disph_teste.geom) AS the_geom,
  ST_Length(disph_teste.geom) As length
  FROM disph_teste
  ) AS t
CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,10000) AS n
WHERE n*2000.00/length < 1;
```

The problem is that the input line has an ***n*** attribute which must be divided by the resulting segments number and increments until it reaches the original attribute value, like the image bellow.
Still can't figure out a way to do so. Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

*I wrote a set of functions to easily handle dividing lines **by length** and **by segment count**, both in* PL/pgSQL *[as simple *.sql* files](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/st_linesubstringsbyvalue.sql), and* C *as [PostGIS core add-ons](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/C/lwgeom_dump_substrings.c) (needs you to build PostGIS yourself) and I'm shamelessly going to promote it's usage here.*

*The following assumes to have **one of both options installed** - with the* PL/pgSQL *option being a trivially easy option!*

Run:

```
SELECT ln.n::FLOAT / MAX(dmp.path[1]) OVER() * dmp.path[1] AS n, dmp.geom
FROM   <lines> AS ln,
       LATERAL ST_LineSubstringsByLength(ln.geom, 2000) AS dmp
;
```

Example:

```
WITH
    ln(n, geom) AS (
        VALUES(10, ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 0, 4 0, 8 0)'::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING), 4236))
    )
SELECT n::FLOAT / MAX(dmp.path[1]) OVER() * dmp.path[1], dmp.geom
FROM   ln,
       LATERAL ST_LineSubstringsByLength(geom, 2.5) AS dmp
;

+--------+-------------------------+
|n       |st_astext                |
+--------+-------------------------+
|2.5     |LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,2.5 0)|
|5       |LINESTRING(2.5 0,4 0,5 0)|
|7.5     |LINESTRING(5 0,7.5 0)    |
|10      |LINESTRING(7.5 0,8 0)    |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

---

Alternatively, **without the function set installed**, run:

```
SELECT n::FLOAT / (MAX(f) OVER() + 1) * (f + 1),
       ST_LineSubstring(ln.geom, f * 2000/len, LEAST((f+1) * 2000/len, 1.0)) AS geom
FROM   <lines> AS ln,
       LATERAL ST_Length(ln.geom) AS len
CROSS JOIN
       GENERATE_SERIES(0, FLOOR(len / 2000)::INT) AS f
;
```

Example:

```
WITH
    ln(n, geom) AS (
        VALUES(10, ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 0, 4 0, 8 0)'::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING), 4236))
    )
SELECT n::FLOAT / (MAX(f) OVER() + 1) * (f + 1),
       ST_AsText(ST_LineSubstring(geom, f * 2.5/len, LEAST((f+1) * 2.5/len, 1.0))) AS geom
FROM   ln,
       LATERAL ST_Length(geom) AS len
CROSS JOIN
       GENERATE_SERIES(0, FLOOR(len / 2.5)::INT) AS f
;


+--------+-------------------------+
|n       |geom                     |
+--------+-------------------------+
|2.5     |LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,2.5 0)|
|5       |LINESTRING(2.5 0,4 0,5 0)|
|7.5     |LINESTRING(5 0,7.5 0)    |
|10      |LINESTRING(7.5 0,8 0)    |
+--------+-------------------------+
```